# Skyrim bug with main quest and civil war quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So at the beginning, I joined up with the Stormcloaks and did the proving myself quest. Then I got the Jagged Crown quest and never finished it. It says to talk to Galmar but I didn't finish.

Then I continued on with the main quest and got the quest Season Unending. It says to talk to Ulfric Stormcloak, but he keeps saying, “What are you doing? You should be out there finding the Jagged Crown.” But when I talk to Galmar, he says, “I can't believe you talked Ulfric into talking with the Imperials. What a waste of time, if you ask me.”

It's in a never ending cycle. I don't know what to do. Also, I'm on Xbox 360.

Comment: I don’t know if this will work, but what happens if you travel to [Korvanjund](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Korvanjund) and try to go inside?

Comment: I tried that and when I walk in there is rubble in the way and I can't go through

Comment: I don’t suppose you have an old saved game you can use, or a PC copy of Skyrim. You could fix this in the console if you can transfer your saved game to a Windows copy of Skyrim.

Answer (score 4):

Please also check your Skyrim updates. I believe this was the bug that was fixed in patch 1.4 (as "Fixed issue where starting "Season Unending" after finishing "Joining the Stormcloaks" would prevent "The Jagged Crown" from starting properly.").

Comment: Patch notes, containing the referenced note: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Patch